# Filtering out common observations between 3 data sets

Tags: r

I have 3 data sets (txt.gz) and I have already subsetted them to include only observations with p-value of 1*10^-6 or less.

Next step is to check for a common name variable (the name refers to SNPs, genetics).

The current table:

```
name        pval

rs2575876   8.20660e-07

rs11834972  4.20460e-07

rs11050138  4.23080e-07

rs12313631  7.13600e-07

rs485538    5.99060e-07
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post `head(your.data)`?

Comment: You question is unclear. What format are your three data frames in? (Showing the code you have so far would help clarify the question). What does "...have SNPs in common SNPs with p-values..." mean?

Comment: I'm guessing that `%in%` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

for a database named b, table(b$name)  will let you see how many times a name has been repeated.

EDIT:  Try this

1. create tables that lists the distinct value of names in each dataset

   a2 <- unique(a$names)

   b2 <- unique(b$names)

   c2 <- unique(c$names)
2. Append them

   R1<-  rbind(a2,b2,c2)
3. Check repeats in this table

   x<- data.frame(table(R1))
4. manipulate the data frame as you like. i.e. find all names that appeared in more than one dataset

   x[x$names>1,]

Comment: Actually I have 3 different datasets with the same variable names ("name" and "pval") and what I am trying to do is first of all filter out pvalues lower than 1*10^-6 for all 3 data sets, I have ndone that separately by subsetting. Next thing is to check if the same observation under "name" e.g. rs12345 exists in 2 data sets or even 3.

Comment: Oh I see. That is interesting.

Comment: yes it is and I have tried a couple of things but they have not given me anything :)

Comment: Do you care how many times it has occured in the same dataset?  or do you only want to know if the name is in 1,2 or 3 dataset?

Comment: if "rs12345" is in   dataset a 3 times, dataset b 2 times, dataset c 2 times, do you want to know the number 7, or the number 3?

Comment: I only want to know if any same "name" exists with a pvalue of less than 1*10^-6 (I have already filtered out the p-values) in any 2 or 3 data sets. The data sets are different traits and I am checking if the same "name" of "mutation" exists in more than 1 trait. Hope this makes sense :)